# Dynamically resize JQuery modal Dialog to IFrame content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe

I've got a JQuery dialog with an internal iFrame, which uses a php document to be filled with an image and some info. It works correctly, but if I click one of the images to go to the complete size image and show it in the iFrame, the dialog doesn't resize.

This is how the iframe and dialog get created, I've erased some extra code, but here it's the important thingy:

```
$('<iframe id="frameProductos" width="100%" src="articulos_info.php?codigo_art='+val+'" name="frameProductos">').appendTo('body');

                  var dialog = $("#frameProductos");

                 dialog.dialog({
                      title: 'Revisión de producto',
                      resizable: false,
                      modal: true,
                      position: ['center',150],
                      overlay: {
                          opacity: 0.5,
                          background: "black"
                      },
                      open: function( event, ui ) {

                          $('#frameProductos').width('100%');
                      },
                     close: function( event, ui ) {
                         $(this).dialog('destroy').remove();
                     },
                      width: 500,
                      height: 500,
                      buttons: {
                          "Cerrar": function () {
                              $(this).dialog('destroy').remove();

                          }

                      }
                  });
```

I need the dialog and iFrame to change their sizes if the content's size changes (when the image gets clicked, and the full resolution image appears).

Comment: In fact you could add a js function that resize the iframe and also the dialog and called this function from child window when a image is on full size.

Answer (score 0):

Important Tip: you must update size of iframe after load completed

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //do somthing like this
        window.parent.resizeIframe();
    });
```